# Configure Load test in Visual Studio 2012 ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2012, customization, load-testing

I am currently using the load wizard to create a new load test in Visual Studio 2012. Through this wizard I can configure load distribution, virtual users etc. When I open this load test file through a xml editor, it shows a xml file which is a very long list of different nodes.

My question is that I want to create the load test not through the wizard but rather than code and generate all these settings through an xml file. Is there a way to write a code for load test project. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a load test plugin, where you can read a config/xml file and set the values.
[For more details on Load Test Plugin see this link](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=load%20test%20plugin)

Thanks.